# not able to rotate a moving object in c using opengl

Tags: c, opengl, glut

i am trying to rotate a object while its moving, but i am not able to make it move and rotate along the point i want it to move.

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

// A line between two points.

struct line {
    struct point start;
    struct point end;
};

float j = 100.0;
float rotationAngle = 0.0f; // The angle of rotation for our object  

void rotateObjectWithMovement(void functionToDrawObject(), struct point pivot, float rotationAngle) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(pivot.x, pivot.y, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    functionToDrawObject();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void rotateObjectWithoutMovement(void functionToDrawObject(), struct point pivot, float rotationAngle) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(pivot.x, pivot.y, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(-pivot.x, -pivot.y, 0.0f);
    functionToDrawObject();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void rocket() {

    struct point allPoints[2] = {
        { 100, 100},
        { 150, 150}
    };      
    struct line line1 = {allPoints[0], allPoints[1]};
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    drawLines(&line1, 1);
}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    struct point pivot={j,100};
    rotateObjectWithoutMovement(rocket,pivot,rotationAngle);
    //rotateObjectWithMovement(rocket,pivot,rotationAngle);

    //reference line
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(0, 100);
    glVertex2d(1000, 100);
    glEnd();

    j += 1;  

    rotationAngle += 0.5f; // Increment our rotation value  
    if (rotationAngle > 360.0f) // If we have rotated beyond 360 degrees (a full rotation)  
        rotationAngle -= 360.0f; // Subtract 360 degrees off of our rotation
    glutSwapBuffers(); // Swap our buffers
}

void myinit() {
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 988.0, 0.0, 999.0);
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(700, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Hierarchical Modeling 2D Example");

    myinit();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

rotateWithMoment() function takes a object, static co-ordinates and angle that the object has to be rotated to and rotates it with the statis co-ordinats as the pivot.
 rotateWithoutMovement() function takes a object, changing co-ordinates and angle that the object has to be rotated to and rotates it with the changing co-ordinats as the pivot (example: rotating a lines looks like wheel rotating) sending changing co-ordinates to this function making the line rotate in manner.
I have been trying to get it to work for 2 days and dont know where i am going wrong.

I am trying to get the object i sent to be moved to a (x,y) point and rotated at a specified angle. To do this i was trying to build the function which will do this by accepting the function to draw the object to be rotated and moved. 
 rotateWithoutMovement works great if i send a constant co-ordinate to it.

Comment: Define "don't work".

Comment: Where is your `main(...)` function?

Comment: I don't understand the C++ tag. Your title says "C" language.  They are different languages.  For example, C++ has `std::vector` and `std::string` and C doesn't.  In C, I can name a variable "class" without errors.

Comment: How can you access `allPoints[5]` when the `allpoints` is an array of 2?  Where are those extra 3 elements?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i have changed the code please now. please tell me your observation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i have edited my description. please tell me if there a way to get it to work.

Comment: @ryyker i have added the main function to the code.

Answer (score 2):

Your functions seem either to make assumptions you have not disclosed or to have fewer parameters than they need.  In particular, the axis about which you want to rotate *relative to the object's coordinates* is not specified.

Only rotations about axes that pass through the center of the object are without net movement of the object -- rotations about the vertex centroid preserve the centroid; those about the center of (virtual) mass preserve the center of mass.  OpenGL rotations applied via `glRotatef()` are always about axes that pass through the origin, so generally, you need to perform this logical series of operations:

1. Choose a point `P0` that resides on the desired rotation axis (e.g. the vertex centroid).
2. Apply a translation that moves `P0` to the origin.
3. Apply the desired rotation.
4. Apply a translation that takes the origin back to `P0`.

You can combine that with an additional translation to effect object movement.  Either

- perform the translation before (1), accounting for it during (1) / (2), or
- perform it after or in combination with (4).

If we assume that your `functionToDrawObject()` defines a drawable object in terms of coordinates such that the desired rotation axis passes through the origin already -- as it seems you are indeed assuming -- then (1) and (2) are unneeded, as the required translation is zero.  Otherwise, you would need to provide the wanted pivot point in the object's coordinate system, separately from the desired location of the object in the world coordinate system.  Let us make that assumption.

Before we write the functions, we need to know one other thing: OpenGL defines the current matrix as one that multiplies coordinates on the left: `Matrix` * `X` = `X'`, and when you apply a new transformation (rotation, translation, or scale), its matrix is combined with the current matrix *on the right*, as `Current` * `M` = `New`.  Effectively, this means that the program order in which you want to apply matrices is the reverse of the logical order in which you want them to be applied to graphics coordinates, or equivalently, that the structure of the program mirrors the structure of the matrix equation it encodes.

Your wanted functions would thus have this form:

```
void rotateObjectWithoutMovement(void functionToDrawObject(), struct point pivot,
        float rotationAngle) {
    glPushMatrix();
    // No translation needed, because we're rotating around the object's
    // natural origin (thus pivot is unused) ...
    glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    functionToDrawObject();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void rotateObjectWithMovement(void functionToDrawObject(), struct point pivot,
        float rotationAngle) {
    glPushMatrix();

    // Translate to the desired position after rotating to orient the object
    // as desired.  No additional translation is needed because we did not
    // apply any before the rotation.
    glTranslatef(pivot.x, pivot.y, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    // No _initial_ translation needed, because we're rotating around the object's
    // natural origin ...
    functionToDrawObject();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Note also that no translation applied prior to the rotation affects the final orientation of the drawn object -- such translations affect only the object's location within the scene (as, of course, is also true of translations applied *after* the rotation).

I suspect, however, that our earlier assumption is not really one you want to make.  In that case what you actually want is probably something more like this:

```
void rotateObjectWithMovement(void functionToDrawObject(), struct point pivot,
        float rotationAngle, struct point translation) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(pivot.x + translation.x, pivot.y + translation.y, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(-pivot.x, -pivot.y, 0.0f);
    functionToDrawObject();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void rotateObjectWithoutMovement(void functionToDrawObject(), struct point pivot,
        float rotationAngle) {
    static const struct point zero = { 0, 0 };
    rotateObjectWithMovement(functionToDrawObject, pivot, rotationAngle, zero);
}
```

Comment: i tried this approach. It does not work. i am getting the same output. the object rotates around a the whole screen.

Comment: Both variations work fine for me, @NaseeruddinVN, given appropriate inputs.  Note that the first variation was prepared before you provided a complete example; your subsequent edits to the question appear to show that, just as I suspected, you indeed do want the second variation instead.  Be sure to pass the correct arguments.